# Is there always a nonbipartite Cayley graph?

Tags: group-theory, cayley-graphs

The question is exactly as in the title. To be more precise, let $G$ be a fin. gen. group and let $C(G,S)$ be its Cayley graph (where $S$ is a set of generators of $G$ such that $S^{-1}=S$). Obviously to different $S$ can correspond different graphs: for example, $C(\mathbb{Z}^2,\{\pm(1,0),\pm(0,1)\})$ and $C(\mathbb{Z}^2,\{\pm(1,0),\pm(0,1),\pm(1,1)\})$; the first is bipartite and the second is not. My question is whether this phenomenon is general, i.e. if we can always find a nonbipartite Cayley graph.

My attempt:

It's not difficult to prove that $C(G,S)$ is nonbipartite iff there is no subgroup $B$ of index $2$ of $G$ which does not intersect $S$. However, this does not really help me as it translates the problem to a group-theoretic one that I don't really see how to approach.

Suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Consider ${\mathbb Z}_2$.

Comment: Take any connected bipartite example (so the bipartition will be unique), then add an element from the bipart of the identity to the connection set, you will get a non-bipartite example. If you write the details carefully, you will see this works unless $|G|\leq 2$.

Comment: @Pelota Your statement about non-bipartite Cayley graphs is wrong. For example, the graph $\operatorname{Cay}(A_4,(123),(132),(12)(34)$ is not bipartite, but there are no subgroups of index $2$ in the group $A_4$.

Comment: @kabenyuk Indeed you are right, I meant the opposite (i.e. if there is no such $B$). I'll edit the question

Comment: If your question is to find all those groups for which each Cayley graph is bipartite, then the answer is this. A group has this property if and only if its order is not greater than two. In fact, if $|G|>2$, then let us take $S=G\setminus{e}$. The graph $\operatorname{Cay}(G,S)$ is a complete graph with $|G|\geq3$ vertices. Therefore it is not bipartite.

Comment: @kabenyuk  I was tempted to make the same comment, but because the OP mentioned finitely generated groups, I thought that maybe they would prefer an example with finite $|S|$, which can also be obtained as in my comment.

Comment: Thank you, @verret. Honestly, I didn't understand your comment at first, although I reread it several times, that's why I wrote my comment about finite groups. But now I think I understand you. Let $\operatorname{Cay}(G,S)$ be a Cayley graph and $s,t\in S$ such that $t^{-1}s\neq1$. The Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cay}(G,S\cup\{t^{-1}s\})$ contains a triangle and hence is not bipartite. Next we have to consider special cases: $|S|=1$ and $S=\{s,t\}$ but $t^{-1}s=1$, which entail that $|G|=2$.

Comment: @kabenyuk I find it easier to think this way: if the graph $\mathrm{Cay}(G,S)$ is already non-bipartite, then we are done. If it is bipartite, then because it is connected, it has a unique bipartition. Take an element $x$ from the same "side" as the identity, other than the identity. (We can always do this unless $|G|=2$.)
Now, the graph $\mathrm{Cay}(G,S\cup\{x,x^{-1}\})$ will be non-bipartite. (Because they are in the same "part", there is a path of even length from $1$ to $x$, which together with the new edge, creates an odd cycle.)

Comment: @kabenyuk I think your explanation is also fine, but there a few little details off. For example,  you need to add the inverse of $t^{-1}s$ to $S$. But also, $S=\{s,t\}$ and $t^{-1}s=1$ is actually the same case as $|S|=1$.

Comment: @verret
About the little details I absolutely agree with you.